# framework for getting the UI in a webworks app

Tags: css, blackberry-webworks

What are good frameworks to get the UI style of a blackberry 10 app?

I know how to use webworks but the UI looks standart HTML like and I dont want to build my own CSS classes for a bb10 design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [bbUI](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js) or [jQueryMobile BB10 Theme](https://github.com/blackberry/jQueryMobile-BB10-Theme).

But I would recommend bbUI